# Preserve msg.sender but not storage

Tags: solidity, evm, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

In this particular scheme, we pass the address of the `Attacker` contract in `Victim.foo`.

By using **delegatecall**, we maintain the `msg.sender` field, **but** we are not using the storage of `Storage` but `Attacker`'s.

Is the `Victim` contract vulnerable to an attack where the `msg.sender` field is maintained (here it would be `Victim`'s address) **and** using the storage of `Victim` too?

```
contract Victim {
  uint some;
  function foo(address _contract) {
    // ....
    SomeInterface(_contract).changeStorage(10);
    //....
  }
}

contract Storage {
  uint value;
  function changeStorage(uint _value) {
    require(msg.sender == victim);
    value = _value;
  }
}

contract Attacker {

  function changeStorage(uint _value) {
     bytes memory data = 0x.. //abi-encoded changeStorage with some value
     execute(victim, data);
  }

  function execute(address _target, bytes memory _data) {
    (bool success,) = _target.delegatecall(_data);
  }
}
```

Comment: "but we are not using the storage of B but Attacker's." - totally unclear IMO. You may want to start off by describing the entities in your system, and explaining the role of each one of the in the scenario that you are trying to present. While it's arguable that `Attacker` and `Victim` are self-explanatory, it is not arguable that `B` is totally **not** self-explanatory.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `B` is. You can name it however you want, the key is that only `Victim` can change its storage. I changed the name to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm understanding from the code and question: If A calls B, and B delegatecalls C, are state changes in the C execution affecting the storage in A?

The answer is no, it isn't. Since Victim is calling Attacker, Attacker's storage becomes the storage operated on and Victim is the msg.sender. Then when Attacker delegatcalls into Storage, it retains Victim as the msg.sender, as well as the storage operating on as Attacker.

The only way here to modify the storage in Victim is for Victim to delegatecall Storage directly.